# How do I make it so when I enter itemType it prints out the an actual type not just an Int

Tags: java

```
package Homework;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework2LibraryFines {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Variables
    int cardNumber;
    int age;
    int overdue;
    int itemType;
    double overdueFine;
    int fineAdjustment;
    int books = 1;
    int magazines = 2;
    int dvd = 3;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter patron's library card number");
    cardNumber = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter patron's age");
    age = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter item type 1.Book, 2.Magazine, 3.DVD");
    itemType = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter number of days overdue");
    overdue = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter overdue fine");
    overdueFine = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter fine adjustment");
    fineAdjustment = input.nextInt();
    if (overdueFine == books) {
        overdueFine += 0.50;
    } else if (overdueFine == magazines) {
        overdueFine += 0.25;
    } else if (overdueFine == dvd) {
        overdueFine += 1.50;
    } else if (age > 70) {
        overdueFine += 0;
    } else if (age >= 6 && age <= 17) {
        overdueFine += 1.00;
    }

    System.out.println(cardNumber + " is " + age + " years old " + "and has an overdue " + itemType + "." + "The "
            + itemType + " is " + overdue + " days overdue");

}
```

}

> ### OUTPUT
>
> Enter patron's library card number
>       222222
>       Enter patron's age
>       30
>       Enter item type 1.Book, 2.Magazine, 3.DVD
>       3
>       Enter number of days overdue
>       10
>       Enter overdue fine
>       2.00
>       Enter fine adjustment
>       3
>   222222 is 30 years old and has an overdue 3.The 3 is 10 days overdue

Comment: Have you thought about some solution ? Condition, switch, enum, ..

Comment: Please format your questions better, and always let us know what all you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Not that beautiful but it works:

```
string itemName = "";

if (itemType == 1) itemName = "Book";
else if (itemType == 2) itemName = "Magazine";
else if (itemType == 3) itemName = "DVD";
```

And when printing it out just replace *itemType* by *itemName*.

Comment: `switch` is also a good solution (a bit less verbose since we don't need to repeate `itemType ==`

Comment: True, but as he seems to be a beginner I tried to make the solution as easy as possible

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `switch` statement to get the actual `String` value depending on the number entered

```
String item="Book";//making Book the default option
        switch (itemType) {
            case 1:
                item = "Book";
                break;
            case 2:
                item = "Magazine";
                break;
            case 3:
                item = "DVD";
                break;
        }
```

And print `item` in the `print` statement.

Or even a somewhat ugly `ternary` condition

```
String item = itemType == 1 ? "Book" : itemType == 2 ? "Magazine" : itemType == 3 ? "DVD" : "Book";
```

Comment: You don't need the `default` here, or you can just declare `item` and put default initialization in the `default`.

Comment: @AxelH true - it's a habit to add a default though :)

Comment: Ok thanks this made me understand switch statements a little more. Also do you know how I make it so each time the program is executed it calculates the fine for a single item.  If the user enters invalid data, then a message must be presented on the screen specifying the invalid information and the calculation is aborted.

Comment: I would have prefered you keep the `default` and set `"item = "aDefaultValue"` in it ;) but that's my preference...

Comment: @Safo I probably could, but it's best not to answer multiple questions on the one question, if that makes sense. If you're struggling with calculating the fine amount, ask a new question and provide your attempt (including input / output entered) and point us to what is not calculating correctly.

Comment: @notyou yeah that's true. I realized you gotta wait 3 days to ask another question

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make a `switch` statement.

The `itemType` variable stores the option and a second variable store the `string`

```
String itemT = "";
switch(itemType)
{
    case 1:
        itemT = "book"
        break;
    case2:
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the `if` and `switch` solutions already suggested, you can create an `enum`. These are a special kind of class with limited values. You can override the `toString()` method to print out whatever you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare and array of itemTypes, and while printing, use the user input as an offset in the array.

For storing,

```
String itemTypesArr[] = {"", "Book", "Magazine", "DVD"};
```

Now, `itemTypesArr[1]` refers to `"Book"` and so on for others.

For printing,

```
System.out.println(cardNumber + " is " + age + " years old " + "and has an overdue " + itemTypesArr[itemType] + "." + "The " + itemTypesArr[itemType] + " is " + overdue + " days overdue");
```